# Checker for integer string

Tags: java

Got most of the code but can't figure out why I'm getting an compiler error. The error is:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:13)
```

I'm kinda new to java so I'm not too familiar with the error messages. But my program is supposed to check if the numbers 0 through 9 and report if they're numbers with yes. If it contains anything but numbers it'll output a no. If someone could see what i'm doing wrong that'll help

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      boolean thing = true;
        String userInput;
        userInput = scnr.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length() && thing == true; i++)  {
            if (userInput.charAt(i) == '0' || userInput.charAt(i) == '1' || userInput.charAt(i) == '2' ||
                userInput.charAt(i) == '3' || userInput.charAt(i) == '4' || userInput.charAt(i) == '5' ||
                userInput.charAt(i) == '6' || userInput.charAt(i) == '7' || userInput.charAt(i) == '8' || 
                userInput.charAt(i) == '9') {
                thing = true;
                if (i == userInput.length())    {
                    System.out.print("yes");
                    System.out.print("");
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("no");
                System.out.print(" ");
                thing = false;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error - compiler errors are the ones shown while you compile (the `javac` command). This is an exception that you get while you run the program.

Comment: String indexes start at zero. If a String has only 1 character, the only valid index for `charAt` is zero; `s.charAt(1)` will give you the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException that you're seeing. See change your loop to `i < userInput.length()` (`<` rather than `<=`) otherwise the index will go one higher than the last valid index in the string.

Comment: And change your i == userInput.length() to i == userInput.length()-1

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: `userInput = scnr.nextLine(); String yesNo = "NO"; if (userInput.matches("\\d+")) { yesNo = "YES"; } System.out.println(yesNo);`